# NSString stringWithFormat less parameters

Tags: ios, nsstring

We need to format a string, but for some localisations we won't output all parameters. But it seems that it doesn't work to output less parameters than passed:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%2$@", @"<1111>", @"<22222>"];
NSLog(@"String = %@", string);
```

Outputs

```
String = <1111>
```

although i output the second parameter.
Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: It is unclear what you are doing and trying to achieve in your question. Please clarify it.

Comment: you have to use both parameters, you can't just use the second

Comment: according to the industrial standard: _"When numbered argument specifications are used, specifying the Nth argument __requires that all the leading arguments__, from the first to the (N-1)th, __are specified in the format string__."_ ([source](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to the related industrial standard, [IEEE specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html):

> When numbered argument specifications are used, specifying the Nth argument **requires that all the leading arguments**, from the first to the (N-1)th, **are specified** in the format string.

---

which means in other words, you must use the first `%1$@` parameter in your string formatter somewhere before you address to use the second one – so, it is not a bug at all.

Comment: ok means it is impossible to show only the second parameter?

Comment: according to the current standards, yes, that way would not work, I'm afraid.

Comment: thanks... can you imagine another generic solution? Is there another function which supports it?

Comment: you may create a category on `NSString` for handle such scenarios, but nothing official pops into my mind about that at this time.

Comment: If you have some special texts that make no sense to say out in other locale (like special suffix of mother-in-law) then ensure that the argument itself is empty string in that other locale, then you can have the argument specification anywhere in format string.