# Positional Specifier in iOS, Swift 4.x

Tags: ios, swift, string, localization, format-specifiers

**Scenario:** I have a requirement in localization where I need to have values in a string irrespective of their order. An example could be considered as below:

***1st language:***  {username} is {age} old.

***2nd language***   Age {age} is of {username}.

**Positional Specifier:** To achieve this we have something called as positional specifiers. A discussion on this could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1063843/5395919). I tried including positional specifiers in an example code as follows:

```
// Prints "Time is cruel"    
let output = String(format: "%1$@ %2$@ %3$@", "Time", "is", "cruel")

// Prints "Time" but ideally should print the 3rd argument i.e "cruel".
let output1 = NSString(format: "%3$@", "Time", "is", "cruel")
```

***Is there a way to achieve the functionality above? Can it be done via positional specifiers and if can what am I missing?***

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fprintf.html: *"When numbered argument specifications are used, specifying the Nth argument requires that all the leading arguments, from the first to the (N-1)th, are specified in the format string."*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657641/nsstring-stringwithformat-less-parameters/34657997#34657997

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example where you would need this? Your username/age example uses 2 positional parameters in both languages.

Comment: I have edited the question. That is the requirement but my approach to the problem via positional specifier is wrong. It is clear from your above comments and referred links.

Comment: I do not know of a built-in method, you probably have to make your own. That should not be too difficult if only the `%@` format is used. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/34546349/1187415 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/2946649/1187415 for possible approaches (that's Objective-C, but the same ideas can be used in Swift).